# How to set the result of a query as a queryable table?

Tags: mysql, select, datatable

**I am trying to use the result of a query as a table.**

This query works fine:

```
SELECT date, number FROM `table_A`
```

The query below as well --> **its result is `table_B` as a string of character not the table itself**

```
SELECT nametable FROM `list_repository` WHERE id=1
```

But the combined one does not:

```
SELECT date, number FROM (SELECT nametable FROM `list_repository` WHERE id=1) A
```

I expect the resulting query to be

```
SELECT date, number FROM `table_B`
```

**I tried to set a variable but it does not work either**:

```
DECLARE x VARCHAR(150) ;
SET table=( SELECT `nametable` FROM `list_repository` WHERE id=1);
SELECT * from `table`. But it would not work
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does Table_B contains the columns `date` and `number` ?

Comment: Yes it does contain the columns requested.

Comment: I would search *"Dynamic SQL in MySQL"*. What you're trying to do is common, but you'll have to write the entire query as a prepared statement (a string) and then execute it. Keep in mind the security concerns if the query includes user input.

Comment: Be aware that this kind of problem *can* be symptomatic of poor schema design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identifiers (db, table, column names etc) in SQL are static. Therefore you can't populate them at run-time. But you can build a query as a string and execute it via [dynamic SQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). Something along the lines of

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT CONCAT("SELECT * FROM ", nametable)
  INTO @sql
  FROM list_repository
 WHERE id = 1;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

---

An example of wrapping it up into a stored procedure

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp1 (IN id INT)
BEGIN
  SET @sql = NULL;
  SELECT CONCAT("SELECT * FROM ", nametable)
    INTO @sql
    FROM list_repository
   WHERE id = id;
  SELECT @sql;
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END//
```

And then invoking it

```
CALL sp1(1);
```

Comment: Thank you peterm. I am using MYSQL. Does that work on it as well? Where should I insert this in my code, right after BEGIN?

Comment: Yes,  it is MySQL.

Comment: The answer is too generic to solve my problem. Can anyone be more specific?

Comment: The answer given fully covered your original question and then some. If you have a different question or don't know how to apply the given answer in your particular context create a new question on SO.

Comment: Here Peter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57650882/issue-with-complex-mysql-query-using-prepared-statement